# Correct name for equation with negative delay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology

How to correctly call the following equation:
$$
  \dot x(t) = F \big(x(t), x(t+\tau)\big), \quad \tau > 0.
$$
I know, that the equation
$$
  \dot x(t) = F \big(x(t), x(t-\tau)\big), \quad \tau > 0.
$$
is called "delay equation". But what if the delay is negative? What is the correct name of this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a differential equation with advanced (not delayed) argument.